# How does Adobe PDF store the form information?

Tags: pdf, adobe, fdf

I am working on a PDF file which needs to be auto-populated. I researched and found that Adobe forms uses the *[FDF](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/fdf_data_exchange.pdf)* format to export and import the form information. However, when I extracted the `FDF` of this PDF file using `pdftk` it was empty!

```
pdftk <input.pdf> generate_fdf output <output.fdf>
```

You can create a form just like a canvas painting, if so then it will be difficult to auto-populate.

So is `FDF` the only *standard* format in which a `PDF` file exports the form information or are there more out there to look for? Or in other words, if there is no `FDF` can I *definitively* say that it can't be auto-populated in any of the standard ways?

PS: [This](https://hhs.texas.gov/sites/default/files//documents/services/health/medicaid-chip/programs/star-kids/sai-v-2-06.pdf) is the file I am dealing with. It is a bit surprising that Govt documents don't have `FDF` :-).

Update: Based on the information below, I corrected the question to mean `FDF` is the data exchange format; not the internal format.

Comment: *"You can create a form just like a canvas painting, if so then it will be difficult to auto-populate."* - this exactly is the case for your sample gvt file. Other than that, FDF is merely an *export format* for form information, inside the PDF populatable form information are in a structure called **AcroForm**.

Comment: @mkl Thanks. Yeah, I realized `FDF` was only a way to "communicate" and not the real thing. Really appreciate looking into the file :-)